# Getting error while executing java programs of packages from command line

Tags: java, command-line, classpath

I'm executing the programs from command line and using packages in them.
my program file names are TestA.java and TestB.java.

I've executed below initially
javac TestA.java

No issues for the above and it generated the class file as well
for the following i'm observing the issue
javac TestB.java

output :

```
TestB.java:2: error: '.' expected
import TestA;
            ^
TestB.java:2: error: ';' expected
import TestA;
             ^
2 errors
```

and the TestA.java file is

```
package a.b;
class TestA {

    public static void methodPublic(){
        methodPrivate();
    }

    protected static void methodProtected(){
        methodPrivate();
    }

    static void methodDefault(){
        methodPrivate();
    }

    private static void methodPrivate(){}
}
```

TestB.java content is :

```
package a.b;

import TestA;

public class TestB {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TestA.methodPublic();
        TestA.methodProtected();
        TestA.methodDefault();

    }

    public static void methodPublic() {
    }

    protected static void methodProtected() {
    }

    static void methodDefault() {

    }

    private static void methodPrivate() {
    }
}
```

I'm executing the javac by navigating to b folder where these two files exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm executing the javac by navigating to b folder where these two files exist.

You don't want to do that; the fully qualified class name of every class **includes** the package. They form a tree. Much like your filesystem. From the `b` folder move up two directories (to the folder containing `a` - e.g. `cd ../..` or `cd ..\..` on Windows). Then

```
javac -cp . a/b/TestA.java a/b/TestB.java
```

Also, you would normally want that to be written to a "binary" output folder. So

```
javac -cp . -d bin a/b/TestA.java a/b/TestB.java
```

Finally, you don't need to `import TestA` because it is in the same package as `TestB`. But, if you **want** to you need

```
import a.b.TestA;
```

Comment: That worked for Compilation, How about executing?
I'm getting below error :
Error: Could not find or load main class TestB

I tried executing from the root folder as well as from b

Comment: `java -cp . a.b.TestB` - if you used `-d bin` then you want to be in the `bin` folder. Otherwise, the same folder that you ran `javac` from. The package is not optional with `java` or `javac`.